# Trivial edit got approved

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just noticed that [one of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22094913) was edited and got approved by two 10k+ users.

What should I do when some users approve an edit which should not be approved anyway?

Comment: I would have removed the `gulp` reference from title entirely. There is no need to have tag in title. I do agree the edit is trivial and missed a thing or two

Comment: point is why approve it? as it falls in trivial category and same goes for the answer

Comment: See no evil. There is no gain into accepting an edit. I believe they are human and made a mistake.

Comment: Why do you think the edit should not have been approved?

Comment: This is not really a trivial edit, but even then, small edits should be approved if they **improve** the post. They shouldn't just be rejected because they are small.

Comment: The edit improves the title quality. It seems like you're just getting upset over nothing.

Comment: Nitpicking here, you did forget a question mark at the end of your question's title, so technically the edit is an improvement to the title's grammar (though admittedly a very small one).

Comment: The only thing I can complain about is that it was a <2k user who did the edit. It's to minor to be worth putting in the queue. But since it's there, it is the same work to approve it as it is to reject it. The edit DID improve the post, although not by much.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you notice a suggested edit that is *wrong* on your own post, you can go to the suggested edit review and reject it after the fact. Conversely, if you notice a suggested edit on your own post that was unduly rejected, you can go to the suggested edit review and force it approved. These options are only available if the post hasn't been edited since that suggested edit.

If you notice that a suggested edit was accepted but neither makes things better nor makes things worse, then there's nothing to do, really. You can't undo the harm of a useless suggested edit (time wasted in review, bumping of the post). If you notice a *pattern* where a user makes a lot of trivial edits, flag your post for moderator attention and explain what's going on (give links to specific cases, moderators can't read your mind).

---

In [this specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22094913), the suggested edit did improve the post a little. It follows the [guidance on titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648), which is to avoid “tag: sentence fragment”, and instead work relevant information organically into the title. It isn't a huge improvement, but it is an improvement. So you should be happy about that edit.

Comment: No, it did not improve the title, as the information (that this is relevant to Gulp) is already present in the tags. It is noise, in the mild sense of "not actually necessary to understand the question".

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Disagree. Removing the qualifier "with Gulp" makes the title appear to describe a different, and much more general, question.

Comment: @duskwuff ... Which is why there are tags, that specialize the topics of questions. That's what they are for. Grouping questions. Making a question specific. It seems people can't be bothered to read or consider them however... Every information that "in Gulp" adds is also present in the tag existence on the question. The presence of the tag informs a reader that the question is about Gulp. I don't know how to put it in other ways, neither do I understand why people seem to completely overlook it. Do you not see tags on questions? Why ignore them?

Comment: Or, a tad bluntly: is the attention span of our target audience so small we have to prevent them from having to consider tags as well as title when looking at a question?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Tags aren't always visible! Consider the "Related" sidebar on questions, for instance -- tags aren't shown on those.

Comment: Right, that's true @duskwuff. Not sure how important an aspect it is however, considering the amount of questions on the sidebar is orders of magnitude lower than the actual number of questions asked, and as such questions will be much more often read from the main list, I believe. I think the general consensus here however is that it's better if it's there, so that's what we'll do.

Comment: The way I read the guidance, you may at your own discretion include tags if you feel it disambiguate your question, but you are not strongly encouraged nor discouraged from using tags in titles: "You may have to describe a part of your title using words that are already applied from your tags in order to distinguish your question from others and avoid confusion/ambiguity."... "don't explicitly add tags to the title for their own sake"

Comment: @AaronLS the later part is to prevent people from inorganically adding the tags into the title. If your title is "How I can use T-SQL to generate a contingency table?", that's organic. Removing T-SQL would make it too ambiguous instead and put more effort on the reader wondering what that has to do with programming.

Comment: @Braiam I understood and agree. My point is the guidance does not state as an absolute that we should never use tags in titles.

Comment: @AaronLS note, that when the guidance recommends against, is the form of: *[tag]: sentence, or tag - tag -tag - something or something [tag][tag][tag], etc.* when the tag is used as a literal tag, rather than part of the sentence.

Comment: @Braiam Again, I absolute 100% understand and nothing I've said is contrary to that. That's a very **specific** guidance.  I'll state again my point again is: there is no absolute **general** rule that we should never use tags in a title.  What you're quoting is very specific guidance.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier More important than the sidebar questions not having tags, in my opinion, is search engine results not having tags. Many times I've clicked on a question that had a title that looked exactly like my problem, only to find that the tags completely changed the context.

e.g. Google Search: "plot points in python"; title: "How to make a scatterplot from a set of points"; tagged: "matlab"

Comment: @TCulp The search engine point is moot. No, search engines do not only index the title tag of a page. To answer your anecdote with another anecdote: I've never have such problems.

Answer (score 9):

The course of action depends on the edit.

### If the edit is simply trivial and unnecessary...

...there is really not much to do.  Rolling back the edit bumps the post unnecessarily.  But if you feel like you need to do something, you could look into the review history of the users who approved the edit.  If you see something that makes it seem like they have a history of approving bad or unnecessary edits, then you can flag a question they approved an edit on and explain to the mods what you found.

### If the edit makes the post worse or less readable...

... then absolutely roll the edit back.  As before though, if you want to do more, you can check up on the approvers and see if this is a one off issue or a repeating pattern of approving bad or unnecessary edits, and flag for the mods with your findings.

And in both cases, if you find more that you can fix in the post, go ahead and edit it into shape as a new edit or as part of the roll back.

Comment: As time goes by, I am less and less concerned about posts being bumped. I am not sure how much of an argument I think of it anymore. I mean, you are right indeed, it bumps a post, takes some place on the home screen, but is it that important as to prevent making review actions more *correct*?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier my issue is how is it making the review action more correct.  The "damage" is done.  Virtually no one will see that the edit was approved and rolled back.  If the rollback came with an automated way to communicate the problems to the editor and reviewers, and possibly remove the +2 rep, then that changes my opinion, but since it doesn't, why clutter the edit history with another almost as trivial edit (which the rollback would be)

Comment: I am not sure how much more problem is caused by a _second_ bump fairly close to the first... One might as well take the time to check for any further improvements

Comment: @psubsee2003 I do think rolling back an edit will remove the +2, that's part of the goal. When posts are removed, the reputation from edits is removed as well, so I presume it's the same with edits.

Comment: @SurajRao that is assuming the trivial edit was seen right away.  What if weeks or months went by?

Comment: @psubsee2003 then being bumped to the front page will totally not be a problem

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier if it does that, then it is a new feature.  I don't remember that happening before though

Comment: @psubsee2003 in an extreme case sure.. But the suggested edit queue hasnt had that much of a clog

Comment: @SurajRao I mean scenerios like question edited 6 hours ago or even 6 months ago but the edit wasn't seen until today.

Answer (score -12):

Roll the edit back, possibly point the editor and reviewers to guidance about tags in titles, how they should not be there.

After rolling back the edit, do improve the title (we don't want the tag: title form).

The point of rolling back, is so that the editer has a chance to notice the change in reputation (one loses reputation from edits that are rolled back).

I hope you have the time and the will to verify if the users have a habit of doing those, which could warrant a mod flag.

---

This was not only a trivial edit but also a wrong one. These users were possibly robo-reviewing, but unless they consistently do so, let's assume they both misclicked.

Comment: What is wrong about the edit? It doesn't make a lick of difference and so is utterly pointless, but it doesn't change the meaning or anything.

Comment: @Gimby if it is pointless, it is needlessly occupying the queue and reviewers need to take extra time to make the real fix

Comment: @SurajRao there are a infinite quantity of reviewers, and reviewers can always skip if they believe the edit they are reviewing is a waste of time.

Comment: @Braiam There is obviously not an infinite quantity of reviewers, as queues are not always empty. Also, we want *good* reviewers. If they never get the signal, through comments or else, that they're not really improving the site, they nevver will improve the site.

Comment: @SurajRao I know that, that is covered by the 'trivial' part. I'm curious what is meant in this answer because it specifically states that the edit is trivial AND it is wrong.

Comment: @Gimby oh, wrong in the sense that there is guidance in the "how to title things" that is against putting tags in titles, since they are present in the tags. reducing the signal / noise ratio, is the point here. So, both trivial, because the before / after state is quite literally almost the same, and wrong, because the action to be taken should have been to remove the tag.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier you seems to misunderstand, there are an infinite amount of potential reviewers. But, like you, don't review. So, you don't get to decide what the reviewers consider a waste of time, since you don't participate. Reviewers can decide whenever their time is wasted or not, when they get to a particular review. Editors shouldn't self-censor if they believe the post are being improved.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the original title actually actually goes against the tags on titles thing "titles should be questions or at least complete english sentences". So, the edit is following recommendations.

Comment: Agree that this was a trivial and unnecessary edit, but strongly disagree that rolling back the edit is the right course of action.  Why bump the post twice just to roll it back?  Since the edit was not harmful there is no need to roll it back.  Instead, if there is a better edit that could be done, make that one.

Comment: @Braiam Wait a minute... You say I don't review (enough to your taste, since that's obviously false) but your own last review is from [December 21 of 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam?tab=activity&sort=reviews). In comparison, I've had more than [twice as much reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576767/félix-gagnon-grenier?tab=activity) than you over the life of my account, and infinitely more in 2019, since you did exactly 0. You are just inventing dirt on other users. You are the one who should keep silent.

Comment: No, that edit was correct. Not a huge improvement, sure, but it did [follow the guidance on titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648): put relevant information organically in a sentence (“… with Gulp”) instead of using tag soup (“Gulp: …”). _That_ is what “don't put tags in titles” means. It doesn't mean that anything present in tags should be removed from titles! That would be very harmful since in most contexts (search engine results), only the title is available, not the tags.

Comment: @Gilles I don't agree that having "in Python", "in Gulp", "in Go" or in whatever language helps. That information is contained in the tags already. The search engine consideration is possibly relevant however, pages are *also* indexed by google, not only the titles, so I don't know what you mean exactly. I've never not found an answer because a tag I was adding was not in the title. Actually, rarely is the tag in the title, when I find a post.

Comment: Félix, I agree that the tag shouldn't be in the title, but rolling back the edit as you suggest in your answer would make the title worse: it originally said "Gulp: ...", which is definitely worse than "... in Gulp".

Comment: Agreed @Cris, it was kinda obvious to me, but one should edit a question in shape when interacting with it. Clarified that.